# What exactly does the % symbol mean in output context in java

Tags: java

I was recently going over a calculator that a user on this website suggested to me due to my calculator, quite frankly, sucking. here is the code for the calculator:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RealCalc {

// Declare the constants
private static final String YES = "YES";

private static final String MULTIPLY = "Multiply";
private static final String DIVIDE = "Divide";
private static final String SUBTRACT = "Subtract";
private static final String ADD = "Add";

public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Using one only Scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double fnum, snum;

    System.out.println("Hello, my name is Cortana,"
            + " would you like to perform operations with me?");

    // Use equalsIgnoreCase to make it case-insensitive
    if(sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase(YES)) {

        System.out.println("Good choice!\n");

        System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
        fnum = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
        snum = sc.nextDouble();

        // This is used to clear the '\n' character following the previous
        // integer input
        sc.nextLine();

        // Call the function to perform arithmetic operations
        performOperation(sc, fnum, snum);
    }

    System.out.println("Thank you!");
}

public static void performOperation(Scanner sc, double fnum, double snum) {

    System.out.println("\n" + MULTIPLY + ", " + DIVIDE + ", " + SUBTRACT + ", or " + ADD);
    System.out.println("What do you want me to do with these numbers?");    
    String operation = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println();
    if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(MULTIPLY)) {
        System.out.printf("%8.3f * %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum * snum);
    }
    else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(DIVIDE)) {
        System.out.printf("%8.3f / %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum / snum);
    }
    else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(SUBTRACT)) {
        System.out.printf("%8.3f - %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum - snum);
    }
    else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(ADD)) {
        System.out.printf("%8.3f + %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum + snum);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry, I do not recognize this operation.\n");

        // Call this function again to re-prompt the user for a valid operation
        performOperation(sc, fnum, snum);
    }
}
```

}

The problem I am having is with the outputs. Whenever the user inputs the two numbers, it saves them into two different variables, fNum, and sNum. So I was thinking, why can't you just put

```
System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (fNum * sNUM));
//Assuming it is multiplication
```

So where do all of these % signs and 8.3f come in? any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? If the answers were helpful, please upvote or accept them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` is the symbol used in formatted printing (`printf()`) as a placeholder that will be replaced with values. Common examples include `%f` for float, `%d` for decimal integer and `%s` for string. For example:

```
String greet = "Hello"
System.out.printf("%s world!", greet); //prints "Hello world!"
```

`%8.3f` means a placeholder for a float value with a minimum width of 8 and 3 digits after the decimal point. If the value contains less than 8 characters, then by default spaces will be added at the beginning to fill the gap.

Though you can use concatenation, which you mentioned in your answer, `printf()` is more powerful and concise, so it is preferred for complex string formatting.

See [this](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet) reference page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes you could simply use

```
System.out.println("Your answer is: " + (fNum * sNUM));
```

However this will show all the decimal places of your answer.  The %8.3f strings tell the string formatter to format the floaring point number as 8 charachters in width with 3 following the decimal point, take a looks at the java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)